# ImportError: cannot import name 'trace' from 'tensorflow.python.profiler'?

Tags: tensorflow, trace, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator

I installed the GPU-supported tesnorflow 2.2.0, on my machine, then I created a virtual enviorment using conda:
`conda create --name tfgpu220 python==3.8`
And I run these installation commands:
`pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.2.0`
`pip install spyder`
I set the python-interpreter of spyder to use thepython.exe file inside the created virtual env tfgpu220.

Everything runs ok, but when I start using tensoboard, with runing this command in conda console:
`tensorboard  --logdir=logs --port 8088`

I face the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'trace' from 'tensorflow.python.profiler'

When I run pip list I get this:

> tensorboard                   2.2.2 tensorboard-data-server
> 0.6.1 tensorboard-plugin-wit        1.8.1 tensorflow-gpu                2.2.0 tensorflow-gpu-estimator      2.2.0 tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.25.0 termcolor                     1.1.0 text-unidecode                1.3 textdistance                  4.2.2 tf-estimator-nightly          2.8.0.dev2021122109

I suspect version compatbility problem because of the tensorboard 2.2.2 or the tf-estimator-nightly          2.8.0.dev2021122109.

Any help,

thanks.

Comment: Before further investigation the profiler.trace using Python Utilities can I know the versions of the running Python and sources of the installers or sources of the download Tensorflow? Python 3.5-3.8 https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source

Comment: It is loggings monitors and tracings, supplies library does not include a shared library.

Comment: Could you please try again with the latest stable tensorflow version using `pip install tensorflow==2.10`.  All compatible versions of tensorflow estimator / tensorboard automatically get installed with tensorflow package while installing tensorflow. Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.